# why class="btn btn-default" instead of only class="btn-default"

Tags: html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap one thing that is kicking in my ass since many days is that I don't understand the concept behind the tag when including bootstrap classes in HTML.

Like -

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"> press me </button>
```

why there is two? btn and btn-primary. why we don't only include only btn-primary as we want a primary type btn only. What does it mean and what is the purpose of it ?

there are also many examples like this -

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Comment: btn will define all the basics styles for a button and btn-primary will do the background color, like there are classes like btn-success(green) btn-info(blue) etc.

Comment: Thats how we should create style classes which we need to reuse.

Comment: A tag having `class="btn btn-primary"`  does it mean that that tag falls under two classes ?

Comment: that means that tag needs both that css classes for rendering its style.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/aRrtYnS9LO check this example what `.btn`, `.btn & .btn-default` etc etc does

Comment: Ok now I understand. `btn`  is just to specify that we are going to add a button here. then after adding the basic button we add another class like `btn-primary` or `btn-success` to add more on that basic button. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I got a clear understanding of this thing. I am describing it here so it can help other people like me.

```
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">PressMe</button>
```

This kinds of  patterns you will see very often in Bootstrap - Applying two classes to complete a single task. This helps to keep the Bootstrap's CSS file much smaller.

For `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>`

- The .glyphicon class specifies we should use the provided icon font.
- The .glyphicon-calendar class specifies which icon we shound use.

and for `<button class="btn btn-primary">PressMe</button>`

- The .btn class specifies we are going to have a basic button style.
- The .btn-primary class specifies this button should have a style of primary type.

*Awesome Bootstraping...*

Answer (score 2):

The `.btn` and `.btn-primaray` are two different classes and both apply some different style.

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4;
}
```

Tag needs both that css classes for rendering its style.

[Reference](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css)

Comment: General properties are in `.btn`  and extended in `.btn-primary` class basically.

Answer (score 0):

It is two properties: `btn` and `btn-primary`. `btn-primary` is added for styling.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that the way the SCSS compiles out, there really isn't much savings in the output CSS. And, when you consider the extra HTML across all your buttons, you're probably losing rather than saving.

If you wanted you could just merge the classes:

```
.priBtn {
  @extend .btn;
  @include button-variant($btn-primary-color, $btn-primary-bg, $btn-primary-border);
}
```

It's likely just going to [emit using a comma selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend), so it shouldn't grow the CSS much, and you'd be able to use 1 class instead of 2 like you wanted.

That said, this is diverging from the standard Bootstrap, and that does make some purists crazy.

Note: To do the above extend and include, you will need to import the necessary Bootstrap files first. The paths involved vary depending on what kind of SCSS/SASS compiler you're using - many only support relative paths, not absolute, and those relative paths can be pretty bulky.